# How can I subset into dataframes based on unique variable using a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

want to subset a dataset into 4 categories (based on the 4 unique categories) using a for loop. I've tried some subsetting and haven't been successful.

```
ID Region Other
1  North    x
2  South    y
3  West     z
4  East     l
```

I want to subset into 4 dataframes subset by "region"

I've tried the following but am not quite getting it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for region in test.region.unique(): 
    reg = test[test == region]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate groupby object:

```
for group_name, group in df.groupby('column_name'):
    print(group_name)
    print(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice would be to create a dictionary with each df entry like this:

```
df_dict = {x:df.loc[df.Region == x] for x in df.Region}
```